# Why does pidof from homebrew returns always zero?

Tags: homebrew

I've installed `pidof` via homebrew

```
brew install pidof
```

And think about two cases:

```
$ pidof bash > /dev/null; echo $?
$ pidof asdf > /dev/null; echo $?
```

The results are:

```
0
0
```

Why does it happen? Other linux throw 1 when `pidof` couldn't find process.

Comment: "echo $?" is simply showing you whether or not the previous command, in this case "pidof" exited with an error code. 0 means success, any value greater than 0 is an error. I've never used pidof, but surely it returns the process ID of the process you pass it, why are you directing that output to /dev/null? surely "pidof bash" or "pidof asdf" will give you what you what you want?

Comment: Redirecting to /dev/null is just because I don't want to see PID (if it exists). What I wonder is, pidof of linux throws 1 if no PID found, but pidof of Mac OS X always throws 0 even if it doesn't find PID.

Comment: In that case, I don't know why echo $? would return 1 instead of 0 on Linux assuming there was no error. Hopefully someone else will have an explanation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that the `pidof` from HomeBrew is a different program than `pidof` in Linux. Even though they share the same name, and parts of the same functionality, they're actually quite different.

For example the HomeBrew `pidof` will also kill processes for you when specifying the -k argument, which Linux `pidof` cannot do. In contrast Linux `pidof` lets you specify you only want a single PID returned in single-shot mode with the -s parameter, the HomeBrew version hasn't got such an option. There are many other differences.

On Linux, `pidof` comes from the ubiquitous [sysvinit-tools](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit/) package. When you do a `pidof programname` in Linux, it loops through the running processes while keeping track of whether or not it found the program name you're looking for. If it doesn't find it, it returns an exit status of `!0` (which is 1).

In HomeBrew, `pidof` is a standalone utility from ["Night Productions"](http://www.nightproductions.net/cli.htm). Their program has no source in common with the Linux `pidof`, and does not track whether or not it found the program name. It always returns an exit status of 0 in any case.

Comment: Uups, my bad, the `pidof` in my local bin folder wasn't installed via Homebrew...

Comment: @jksoegaard Are you sure that the procps package from sourceforge contains `pidof`? I cannot find any trace of the `pidof` command in [procps-3.2.8.tar.gz](http://procps.sourceforge.net/procps-3.2.8.tar.gz).

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni Ah, you're right - examined the source code of both programs before writing this, but I accidentially wrote the wrong project name here... procps contains a lot of other stuff that is related, but not here.

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the Homebrew formula of `pidof`, you will see that the Homebrew version is built from : http://www.nightproductions.net/downloads/pidof_source.tar.gz

If you look at the source code `pidof.c` used by Homebrew, you will see that each occurrence of the `return` statement in the main function, is in the form:

```
return 0
```

except one time, when the usage of the command is printed:

```
printf("USAGE: %s [-klvh] [PID name]\n",ProgName);
                return 1;
                break;
```

On the other hand, in Linux distributions, such as [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/buster/sysvinit), the `pidof` command is coming  from the [System V style init programs](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/sysvinit). If you download the source code and look at `killall5.c` (which is then linked to `pidof`), you have at the last line of the main function:

```
return retval;
```

where `retval`can be non-null.

So the main reson why the Homebrew version of pidof and the Linux version of pidof return different values is because they use different codebase.